# How do I use another library in my app?

Tags: android, android-studio

The title is a little misleading but I honestly don't know how to word it in any other way. This is my project structure:

[image]

I want to use the highlighted (`fasteranimationscontainer-master`) in my current app that I'm working on. I imported it by putting the jar file in my library folder then adding it to my library through Android Studio. But I try to create an object of that imported library, it doesn't show up/import.

I'm still learning how to use android studio so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please can you add see build.gradle file code to the question?

Comment: Import it as a module in Android Studio then add as a library in your app.

Answer (score -1):

**1. Library with only the Source Code**

To include a library with only the source code (like [FasterAnimationsContainer](https://github.com/tigerjj/FasterAnimationsContainer)) to your project, you only need to import it as a module from **File -> New-> Import Module** in Android Studio:

[image]

There should be a dialog for the project folder, enter the path where your library reside.

Then you need to add the module to your ***app*** **build.gradle** as a dependency:

```
android {
  ...
  dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':fasteranimationscontainer')
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can use it in your project.

**2. Library from Maven or JCenter**

To add dependencies to your project where the library has uploaded to maven or jcenter, you need to modify your ***app*** **build.gradle** file and add extra lines configuring the packages you require. For example, for certain Google or Android, dependencies look like:

```
android {
  ...
  dependencies {
      // Google Play Services
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'

      // Support Libraries
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
  }
}
```

Try to always read the library README first.

---

**Suggestion:**
If you still learning using Android Studio, you can read [Using Android Studio](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Android-Studio). Then read [Getting Started with Gradle](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Getting-Started-with-Gradle), because Android Studio is tightly related with Gradle.

Comment: For the down voter, could you please give the reason for the down vote? I'll stand corrected.

Comment: Right now, I'm getting this error: Error:Dependency Animation Test:fasterAnimationsContainermaster:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\Owen\Documents\GitHub\Animation Test\fasterAnimationsContainermaster\build\outputs\apk\fasterAnimationsContainermaster-release-unsigned.apk    And this is what my gradle looks like: [link](http://imgur.com/a/IMHj8)

Comment: try using 
  `compile project(path: ':fasteranimationscontainer')`. Please be noted that `fasteranimationscontainer` is the module name.

Comment: You need to solve the red lined dependencies first. Try commenting the appcompat-v7. And please remove the "\" at the last line of `play-services-gcm:9.8.0`